# display the posts of Custom Post type in custom category

Tags: custom-post-types

I create custom post type named "project".

and the custom taxonomy of project is named "project_cat".

so my question is that if I create an "apple" taxonomy,and the URL will be **http://localhost/project_cat/apple**.

> how do I display the posts that belong "apple" taxonomy?

```
// Custom post type project
    function ateam_project_post_types(){

        $labels = array(
          'name'              => '全部的專案',
          'add_new'           => '新增任務',
          'add_new_item'      => '新增任務',
          'edit_item'         => '編輯專案',
          'all_items'         => '全部任務',
          'view_item'         => '查看專案',
          'search_items'      => '搜尋任務',
          'not_found'         => '沒有相關專案',
          'not_found_in_trash'=> '垃圾桶裡並沒有相關專案',
          'menu_name'         => '專案管理系統'
        );

        $args = array(
          'supports'          => array('title','editor'),
          'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'project'),
          'public'            => true,
          'has_archive'       => true,
          'hierarchical'      => false,
          'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-text-page',
          'menu_position'     => 1,
          'labels'            => $labels
        );

        register_post_type('project',$args);

      }
      add_action('init','ateam_project_post_types');


    // custom taxonomy of project
    function reg_cat() {

        $labels = array(
          'search_items' =>'搜尋專案',
          'all_items'    =>'所有專案',
          'add_new_item' =>'新增專案',
          'menu_name'    =>'全部專案'
        );

        $args = array(
          'labels'      => $labels,
          'hierarchical'=> true,
          'show_admin_column' => true,
          'rewrite'     => array('slug' => 'project_cat')
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'project_cat',array('project'),$args);

      }
      add_action('init', 'reg_cat');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you've asked this, because doing this wrong is *by far* the most common mistake on this site. It's not even close to whatever #2 is.

The answer is that you don't need to do anything. WordPress will query the correct posts for you based on the URL. You just need to use the normal loop and template tags to display them:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <!-- etc. -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That loop is what loops through the posts that WordPress has already correctly queried based on the URL. So there's no need for any custom `WP_Query`, `get_posts()` or `pre_get_posts` action. Nothing like that.

The exact template that will be used depends on what files are in your theme, and are determined by the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), but all those templates should only include the exact same loop as above. The only reason you'd need to create a `taxonomy-project_cat.php` template is if you wanted this taxonomy's archives to look different or use different markup, and if you did want that then you *still* use that same loop, because the query is always taken care of already.

Comment: oh I understand what you are said.

It` works! thanks!

Comment: so if I want to display the category name,I just use the_category() function or I should use the get_the_term() ??

Comment: Depends where you want to display it. `the_category()` is for displaying the `category` taxonomy, so don't use that. You'd use `the_terms( null, 'project_cat' )` if you wanted to display the project categories on the current project inside the loop, but if you want to display "Apple" as a heading outside the loop, you'd use `single_term_title()`.

Comment: oh I see!! thanks for your detailed and concise answer.I will keep going coding.